# transform proportions to numbers in R

Tags: r

I have this basic problem of statistics:

I have 270 objects of type A B C D in proportion 9:3:3:1. I need to get the number of objects of type A B C and D.

I wish to know whether there is a convenient way to make this computation in R, with oneliner, and be able to change easy the number 270 to any number.

Is there a oneliner that , provided the number N (270) and proportions p1:p2:p3:p4 returns the number of objects , id est.

`N * p1 / sum(p1,p2,p3,p4)`

`N * p2 / sum(p1,p2,p3,p4)`

`N * p3 / sum(p1,p2,p3,p4)`

`N * p4 / sum(p1,p2,p3,p4)`

Comment: Can you just clarify: what is your current data structure?

Comment: It is a problem of statistics that I wanted to solve in R, and I had no idea of a oneliner program -- I do not have experience in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
gimmeNumber <- function(N, props) {
  (N * props)/sum(props)
}

gimmeNumber(N = 270, props = c(9, 3, 3, 1))
[1] 151.875  50.625  50.625  16.875
```